# Change the text of a Tk label asynchronously

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I need graphical output from a Perl program. The window has a `label` status field and should show what programming code decides.

How do I change the text of a label field after the window has been created without any buttons?

I have the following:

```
use Tk;

$mw = Tk::MainWindow->new(-title => 'Status Window',-bg=>"white");    
$mw->geometry ("400x200+0+0");     

$lala = $mw->Label(-text => "Current Status")->grid(-row=>0,-column=>0);    

$mw->bind( 'all' => '<Key-Escape>' => sub {exit;} );

MainLoop;
```

How do I incorporate the following subroutine so that it is run automatically
after the window is created? `Label-Widget` does not have
a `-command` field. It should start immediately and
 not wait for a event to happen

```
sub calculate() {

    for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
        sleep 2s;
        $lala->configure(-text=>"Current Status : $i");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work. I used `after()` to run code after 100 ms then used `update()` to redraw window:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tk;

my $mw = Tk::MainWindow->new(-title => 'Status Window',-bg=>"white");    
$mw->geometry ("400x200+0+0");     
my $lala = $mw->Label(-text => "Current Status")->grid(-row=>0,-column=>0);    
$mw->bind('all'=> '<Key-Escape>' => sub {exit;});

$lala->after(100, \&calculate ); 
MainLoop;

sub calculate() {
    for(my $i=0; $i<10; $i++){
        sleep 1;
        $lala->configure(-text=>"Current Status : $i");
        $mw->update();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The above code blocks during the `sleep 1` call, so any input for the `Tk` event loop will will be delayed. In particular, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to quit the application will not work immediately. It will be blocked until `sleep` returns. To solve this, one can use `Tk`'s `repeat()` instead of `sleep` and `Tk`'s `after()`, and cancel the repeat if necessary:

```
my $repeat_count = 10;
my $timer_id = $lala->repeat(1000, \&calculate ); 

MainLoop;

sub calculate() {
    $lala->configure(-text=>"Current Status : $repeat_count");
    if ( --$repeat_count == 0) {
        $timer_id->cancel;
    }
}
```